# How should I configure httpMessageConverters in Spring boot to convert messages into required format?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, protocol-buffers

I have written an api service using `Spring Boot`, which serves the requests in `Google ProtoBuf` format. My requirement is whenever a user hits my service with accept header as `application-json format` I want to convert the rendered proto objects into `JSON` format using `proto-buf-java Format` (library for converting `JSON` strings to and from proto Objects). Whats happening right now is whenever user hits for `application/x-protobuf` format, spring uses `protobufHTTPMessageConverter` to convert into required format, but when the user hits for Json format spring boot uses default `JacksonMapper` and it couldn't be able to convert into `JsonString`. I am new to `Spring Boot` and I need solution to configure message converters to serve `JSON` format too.

Comment: Did you try to reproduce basic tutorials such as https://github.com/making/spring-mvc-tutorial-protobuf ? If you're stuck, please provide some code, runtime error messages...

Comment: Thanks I forgot to add dependency for Protobuf Java Format in pom.xml. Do you who is maintaining this library http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.protobuf-java-format/protobuf-java-format/1.2. Is this library good to use to convert protos into Json.

Comment: You'll find the name and email of the owner of this library at the bottom of the page you linked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the class below. SpringBoot should scan for it assuming you left AutoScan on. On the request for your API it will return the object serialized to JSON by default or just add &mediaType=json to request.

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class CustomConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters)
    {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.setPrettyPrint(true);
        mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.getObjectMapper().setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);
        converters.add(mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer)
    {
        configurer.defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        configurer.favorPathExtension(false);
        configurer.favorParameter(true);
        configurer.ignoreAcceptHeader(true);
        configurer.useJaf(false);
        configurer.parameterName("mediaType");
        configurer.mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    }
}
```